# Auto-apply of changes when saving in vscode

Tags: nuxt.js, visual-studio-code

I've installed vscode into two different PC, one of them auto-apply the changes I have made in the template of the .vue file that I am working while it doesn't do so in the other unit (*e.g.* When I change a height of a button from `1rem` to `5rem`, I'd be able to see the changes in the Google or Mozilla Firefox browsers either immediately applied or the page reloads automatically without me doing anything to it). The same when I have made changes in the external CSS files that I have in the assets folder.

I have also tried and installed the same extensions (*e.g.* live-server, live-Sass-compiler, vetur, prettier) but the same issue persist in the other PC. Now, I can't access the PC with working auto-apply-changes-made-in-the-template-or-CSS. So **my question is: Does any one have any idea how to enable or restore the function that automatically apply the changes when you save a change in your vscode to your browser.**

Other troubleshooting that I did:

1. Uninstalled and reinstalled vscode completely from the system.
2. Deleted the local folder of the project, cloned them again, and reinstalled the packages.
3. Deleted all extensions and reinstalling them again.

P.S. I use nuxt.js framework while working on the same project.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably coming from a local VScode service not running or some setting that is not mirrored to the other one.

You could maybe compare the 2 instances of VScode's settings, for that: `ctrl + shift + p` (aka Command Palette) and type in `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`.
The concerned setting is maybe about `"editor.formatOnSave": true`, or maybe you don't have an ESlint server running?

Usually, Nuxt (more precisely Webpack itself) just watches the files that are in the project and if you edit those, it will HMR (Hot Module Reload) the page.
If the changes are also related to SSR, it will refresh the page.

You could use this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync
It will allow to sync the settings between the editors. So, install it on the "working" VScode, upload it's settings and download those on the "non working" VScode.

Last thing, you could also try to create a new Nuxt project to see if it HMR/auto-reloads, may be coming from the project too (if something was messed up). On top of the reload probably being faster!

Comment: Hiya, thanks for the reply! I've done the new Project, I mean I've cloned the project on a that "working" computer. I've also tried starting a new git init on a different folder and cloned the same project in the "not-working" unit and it still doesn't work. I just tried syncing another setting config file from my laptop (which has that auto-apply-them-changes-after-saving feature) and it still doesn't work, this included the "editor.formatOnSave" which was already in the "not-working" unit set to true. But all these didn't work for me.

Comment: I haven't tried the extension yet as I am still at work. I have that working feature in my laptop at home, and I will try tomorrow if it works, I'll be coming back after finding a result from this.

Comment: Having the code + installing the dependencies is enough (there is nothing related of it being tracked by git even if a `git clone` is the fastest/easiest way of doing things). Is your repo public? I can try to simply open it and see if it works on my side, that way I could tell you if it's a VScode issue or a project issue (probably VScode but still). The extension is nice because it removes any possible forgettable thing between the 2 VScode instances.

Comment: The project I'm currently working on is private but I have the same project that has the same behavior (if it's really a project related, but I kind of doubt it) here: https://github.com/ypinbong/LouGehwVue.git

Comment: Changed to port to 3000 and it's working fine on my machine too indeed. VScode issue so.

Comment: Btw @YongPin, are you sure that you're editing the correct file? Because I tried the page one but found out that only the component for Login was used.

Comment: Yes I have, I've been working on the project in this "not-working" unit for like 2 weeks now (2 months for the project I gave you the link to). Needless for me to say, but I've worked on multiple(most of it) of its files and I had to reload the browser to see my changes each time. I haven't tried the extension that you recommended but I have tried syncing it with the copy of the settings for my working laptop and it still doesn't have that auto-apply-changes-when-saving feature.

Comment: Can come from a lot of things. Try to replicate the environments as much as you can by syncing all your tooling (code editor, browsers, code etc).

Answer (score 0):

The way it got solved: Reset the problematic PC.

I did not reset the unit to solve this specific problem, but because of some sophos application corruption that required for the problem unit to be reset (I don't know if the said corruption caused this specific problem). Anyway after resetting the problem unit, the unit now works perfectly without any issues.